# Drag & drop Nodes in network graph with Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am starting with Bokeh. I plot a network graph. It works. 
I want to drag & drop on Nodes to move them through plot for better clarity in nodes relation:

So far I have the following (just important lines are written):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=" ", header=None)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(d, 0, 1) 
plot = Plot(background_fill_color="lightgrey",
        plot_width=800, plot_height=600,
        x_range=Range1d(-0.5, 0.5), y_range=Range1d(-0.5, 0.5))
graph_renderer = from_networkx(
    G, nx.spring_layout, scale=1, center=(0, 0))
# here is the issue:
plot.add_tools(PointDrawTool(
    renderers=[graph_renderer], empty_value='black'))
plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)
...
```

`PointDrawTool` is the tool that enables drag&drop. Following documentation says it expects a renderer (I assume: `graph_renderer`) but I get the error `AttributeError: 'GraphRenderer' object has no attribute 'glyph'`

Some guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine in Bokeh v1.1.0 when you replace the

```
plot.add_tools(PointDrawTool(renderers = [graph_renderer], empty_value='black'))
```

with:

```
plot.add_tools(PointDrawTool(renderers = [graph_renderer.node_renderer], empty_value = 'black'))
```